# Pass any model with same base class

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a email service which passes an email model through the constructor and that all using the same base class. For example one model could be for authentication, another model for password reset. My problem is how to allow the service to pass an anonymous model with the same base class.

sample code:

```
public class EmailService<T> : IEmailService 
{
    private readonly T _emailModel;
    private readonly EmailType _emailType;
    private readonly IEmailRepository _emailRepository;
    private MailBuilder _mailBuilder;
    private EmailTemplates _message;


    public EmailService(T emailModel, EmailType emailType, IEmailRepository emailRepository)
    {
        _emailModel = emailModel;
        _emailType = emailType;
        _emailRepository = emailRepository;

        getMessage();
        constructEmail();
    }

    private void getMessage()
    {
        _message = _emailRepository.GetTemplateByUser((int)_emailType, _emailModel.UserTypeId);
    }

    private void constructEmail()
    {
        _mailBuilder = new MailBuilder(_message, _emailType, ObjectConverters.ConvertProperiesToDictionary(_emailModel)); 
    }

    public void Send()
    {
        EmailSettings emailSettings = SiteSettingsService.SiteConfiguration.EmailSettings;

        MailSettings settings = new MailSettings
        {
            MailFrom = emailSettings.MailFrom,
            MailSmtpHost = emailSettings.SmtpHost,
            MailSmtpPort = emailSettings.SmtpPort,
            EnableSsi = emailSettings.EnableSsi,
            MailSmtpUsername = emailSettings.SmtpUsername,
            MailSmtpPassword = emailSettings.SmtpPassword
        };

        new EmailSender(settings).SendEmail(_emailModel.EmailAddress, _message.Title, _mailBuilder.HtmlTemplate);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought of a better way. We always convert our object to a dictionary in the service. Maybe we convert it from the service calling the email service so we're always passing a dictionary instead of an interface, that way we don't need to know about the structure. The dictionary will always be a key value of string and string.

Comment: You lose the benefits of strongly typed objects though.

Comment: There is only one place on the email service that benefits from strongly typed and that is UserTypeId. How the system works is that a Dictionary of named value pairs are compared on the email message brought from the database. The message holds certain key values with a hash on either side. For example a registration message would have welcome #EmailAddress# thank you for registering. Your username is #UserName# . The system would loop through the Dictionary to it matches the key and replaces the hash value with the value from the dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

You could have the derived classes all implement a new `IModel` interface, which your `EmailService` class then accepts via ctor.

```
public class AuthenticationModel : BaseModel, IModel
{
    public void PerformMainFunction()
    {
        // authenticate
    }
}

public class PasswordResetModel : BaseModel, IModel
{
    public void PerformMainFunction()
    {
        // reset password
    }
}

public class BaseModel
{
    public int UserTypeId { get; set; }
}

public interface IModel
{
    void PerformMainFunction();

    int UserTypeId { get; set; }
}

public class EmailService : IEmailService
{
    private readonly IModel _emailModel;
    ...

    public EmailService(IModel emailModel, EmailType emailType, IEmailRepository emailRepository)
    {
        _emailModel = emailModel;
       ...
```

You could use something like unity to inject the dependency or, for now, just do:

```
IModel model = new AuthenticationModel();

var eServ = new EmailService(model, ....
```